# How to set unique name for every html select using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm creating a HTML From with XML and XSLT, then after User submit it, I want to save it to new XML with php. Right now without unique names I have a problem with accessing data via $_POST. So basically I want a unique name for every of my `select`'s in every div, but I don't know how to do it, so please help...

Right now I have 3 times
`select name="Correct"`  `select name="ErrorOne"` `select name="ErrorTwo"`
and I want :
`select name="Correct1"` `select name="ErrorOne1"` `select name="ErrorTwo1"`
`select name="Correct2"` `select name="ErrorOne2"` `select name="ErrorOne2"`
etc...

My form and effect I'm looking for (red line - what I need)[image: form]

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<labels>
    <tags>
        <tag type="Tag1"/>
        <tag type="Tag2"/>
        <tag type="Tag3"/>
    </tags>
    <statuses>
        <status type="Correct">
            <answer description=""/>
            <answer description="Y"/>
            <answer description="N"/>
        </status>
        <status type="ErrorOne">
            <answer description=""/>
            <answer description="whyyy"/>
            <answer description="also this"/>
            <answer description="and THIS!"/>
            <answer description="unknown"/>
        </status>
        <status type="ErrorTwo">
            <answer description=""/>
            <answer description="whyyy"/>
            <answer description="also this"/>
            <answer description="and THIS!"/>
            <answer description="unknown"/>
        </status>
    </statuses>
</labels>
```

My XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <form method="POST" action="scripts/form.php">

            <div class="mainC">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/labels/tags"/> 
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="linkData"/>
        </form>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tags/tag">
            <div class="columnDiv">
                <h3><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></h3>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/labels/statuses"/>
            </div>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="status">
        <div class="subDiv">
            <label><xsl:value-of select ="@type"/></label>
            <select name="{@type}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./answer"/>
            </select>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="answer">
            <option name="{@description}"><xsl:value-of select="@description"/></option>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [position()](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_position.html) function to find the position of the current `<tag>` element within its parent, giving you 1, 2, 3... for each tag.

The only snag is that you have to evaluate `position()` in the `tag` template (because this is where `<tag>` is the context node), and then pass the value down to the `status` template as a parameter. Also, so that `position()` counts which `<tag>` you are on within `<tags>`, you need to change the `match=` of the `tag` template to match just a `<tag>`, and call this template within the context of a `<tags>` parent node.

So, the top-level template looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/labels/tags">
    <form method="POST" action="scripts/form.php">
        <div class="mainC">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tag"/> 
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="linkData"/>
    </form>
</xsl:template>
```

... and then the `tag` template:

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
    <div class="columnDiv">
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></h3>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/labels/statuses">
            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="position()" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

... and the `status` template looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="status">
    <xsl:param name="pos" />
    <div class="subDiv">
        <label><xsl:value-of select ="@type"/></label>
        <select name="{@type}{$pos}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./answer"/>
        </select>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This works perfect. Only top-level template need
`<xsl:template match="/">`
and `<xsl:apply-templates select="/labels//tags/tag"/>`. Without it we get one more iteratiotion thats outside of divs. Ofc thats outside of this question. Thank you for your quick help.

Answer (score 0):

As you map `status` elements to `select` elements, use

```
<xsl:template match="status">
    <div class="subDiv">
        <label><xsl:value-of select ="@type"/></label>
        <xsl:variable name="n"><xsl:number/></xsl:variable>
        <select name="Correct{$n}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./answer"/>
        </select>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: With this I got `Correct1` `ErrorOne2` `ErrorTwo3`. And I need `Correct1` `Correct2` etc.. (New number for every `<tag type="Tag"/>`)

Comment: I have edited the answer to use a constant prefix `Correct` before the computed index number.